# Refer to Ran-GEF as a coenzyme?

Tags: molecular-biology

Ran-GEF facilitates an exchange of GDP for GTP in the formation of Ran-GTP in the nucleus as part of gated import of proteins. Would I be correct in calling Ran-GEF or Ran-GAP coenzymes?

Answer (score 2):

coenzymes are factors that bind to the enzyme so that enzyme can show its activity. In this case conversion between Ran GTP and Ran GDP are caused by hydrolysis and phosphorylation reactions. Ran GEF and Ran GAP are not binding to Ran GTP or Ran GDP.

Comment: *Cofactor* perhaps?